# Grant permission for creating stored procedure, view and using Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server.

User already exist in a database and now he is requesting access for creating `sp`, `views` and fetching data using `select` query. Please tell me how to grant using ssms or t-sql

P.S: I already googled and it's really confusing since some of the sites using "`Alter` Schema" too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [login];
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO [login];
GRANT SELECT TO [login];
```

[And so on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

select user login ID: SECURITY : - LOGINS or if not there create new user id in server role as public.. under user mapping select database then select membership as db_datareader